# calabash-android : querying for nested elements

Tags: cordova-3, intel-xdk, calabash-android

So far I have been able to query elements that are in a flat structure: query("*").
I am using intel AppFramework, and, the structure of the html code is very hierarchical.

How can I query the inner elements of the heavy nested HTML structure ?

Comment: i have seen the same issue here:http://grokbase.com/t/gg/calabash-android/1426ak0pr6/unable-to-find-buttons-with-query

Comment: Is AppFramework compatible with Calabash-android ?